# How to handle dynamically expanding web form?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, webforms, dynamic

I'm looking for a strategy or solution for the following scenario.

I have a one page form (created in .net using c#) that requests some general information about the user as well as a "product" in which the user can add one or more of before submitting the form. The "product" has it's own set of fields (hope that makes sense).

Using javascript to facilitate the user adding this product one or more times, I'm looking for an elegant solution on how I should set up this form. Do I need a whole new set of .net controls each time the product is added? Can I re-use the controls and store the values separately? Is there a way to dynamically create a set of controls each time the user adds another product?

I'm more of a javascript developer, so as you can see, interacting with .net is where I'm still learning. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on you how envision the UI really. Let's say you have a grid of products. To add a new product or to edit you can always pop-up a nice edit/details window and add new product to the gridview. That way you do not need a big real estate area for the UI. 
Btw, Telerik grids (mvc and regular aspx) provide nice interfaces for this kind of behavior.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was not worded clearly. I don't mean a product in the general sense, where the user specifies quantity and adds it to a cart. What I meant was a product, meaning a set/group of input fields - like an object I guess. Does that make any more sense, or did I make you more confused?